# Find similar numbers from a txt file and save the matched numbered lines in different txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk

The main txt (data.txt) contains for example:

```
Lib ID 4444
QT ID 4444
SOQ ID 80
MAC ID 21563
LED ID 4444
TRD ID 80
CAD ID 31256
OIL ID 21563
MNO ID 3315
TOP ID 638
```

And the list goes on. The numbers are from minimum 2 to 5 digits. What I am trying to do is to match the same numbers and save them in separated txt files. The files can be saved by the number's name or it can be anything random. For example, it will save the below IDs in a separate txt file (4444.txt or random.txt):

```
LED ID 4444
QT ID 4444
Lib ID 4444
```

It will save 80 in different txt:

```
TRD ID 80
SOQ ID 80
```

Save another match in different txt:

```
OIL ID 21563
MAC ID 21563
```

And the lines with unique numbers will be saved in a different txt for example (unique.txt):

```
MNO ID 3315
TOP ID 638
CAD ID 31256
```

I have tried using this regex:
`(\d)(?!\1+$)\d*`

it matches the similar numbers but I am stuck on separating them. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q66304300.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2,*delims= " %%u IN ("%filename1%") DO (ECHO %%u %%v %%w)>>"%destdir%\%%w.txt"
FOR /f %%e IN ('dir /b /a-d "%destdir%\*.txt"') DO (
 SET "multiline="
 FOR /f "usebackqskip=1" %%b IN ("%destdir%\%%e") DO SET "multiline=%%b"
 IF NOT DEFINED multiline TYPE "%destdir%\%%e">>"%destdir%\oncers.txt"&DEL "%destdir%\%%e"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

from each line in the sourcefile, select each of the 3 columns to `%%u`, `%%v`, `%%w` and append to a filename (3rd column).txt in a presumed-empty destination directory.

Then read each file from the destination directory. If it has only 1 line, then append it to `oncers.txt` in the destination directory and delete it.

Comment: It'd be useful to state what tool/language that is (looks like BASIC to me but idk) and how to execute it on the example in the question.

Comment: Those days. really haven't seen much of that since I swithed to Linux in -93. Had hair and my Windows 3.1. :D

Comment: @EdMorton : It's batch, like in the taglist. Just set up the source and destination directory names to suit (OP's) system and replace the filename with the actual name of the file. I use a set of directories for testing that includes spaces in the names to test that particular aspect, which can be a stumbling block, and save OP's data in a file named `q????????` where `????????` is the question number so that I can distinguish which set of data applies to each solution.

Comment: @Magoo thanks for the info. Obviously there are several tools mentioned in the tag list, only 1 of which I'm very familiar with, and i had no idea if this was related to the "batchfile" or "norepad++" or "emeditor" tag. I still don't know how you'd actually execute that script (I assume you save it in a file and call some tool to compile it and then you can execute it or you call call some tool passing it that file to interpret) but hopefully the OP does and now there's a clue that people like me who don't know how to use it could google for more info.

Comment: @JamesBrown yeah, BASIC was the 2nd language I learned (after Fortran) when my high school got it's first computer, an [Apple II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II). Looked very much like the code in this answer IIRC but it's been 40+ years so I may be misremembering...

Comment: @Magoo great work on this batch. It is working perfectly for me. The script was easy to understand and I was able to set the directories and file name as preferred.  I am on windows so it is much easier to work with batch scripts and it is more compatible with my other programs. Other scripts are great as well but this is the best solution for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if ( $3 in key2out ) {
        out = key2out[$3]
        if ( $3 in key2first ) {
            print key2first[$3] > out
            delete key2first[$3]
        }
        print >> out
        close(out)
    }
    else {
        key2out[$3] = $3 ".txt"
        key2first[$3] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (key in key2first) {
        print key2first[key] > "unique.txt"
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
$ head *.txt
==> 21563.txt <==
MAC ID 21563
OIL ID 21563

==> 4444.txt <==
Lib ID 4444
QT ID 4444
LED ID 4444

==> 80.txt <==
SOQ ID 80
TRD ID 80

==> unique.txt <==
TOP ID 638
MNO ID 3315
CAD ID 31256
```

Comment: Great work on this script. I am currently on windows so batch script is more preferable option for me.

Comment: You know GNU awk runs on Windows too, right? Anyway, going forward you might consider asking for batch scripts first and THEN asking for other languages if you can't get that so people don't waste their time posting scripts in languages you don't really want to use.

Comment: Let me rephrase that, I find it more comfortable to use batch than awk. I do have Gawk installed on my windows. I asked for other tags because I wanted to have other options to do this. Have you tried a batch script before on windows? It is more easy to understand and to work it. And it doesn't require third party programs like gawk. Anyway, thanks for your time and hard work. It didn't go waste, i find your script to be the best for Awk, I am sure others will find it useful too.

Answer (score 6):

Another awk that creates files named `1` ... *`n`* (var `f` in code):

```
$ awk '{
    if(!($3 in a) && !($3 in u)) {
        u[$3]=$0
        next
    }
    if($3 in u) {                    # u hash holds uniques
        a[$3]=++f                    # file naming happens here
        print u[$3] >> a[$3]    
        print >> a[$3]
        close(a[$3])
        delete u[$3]                 # delete from unique hash when not unique anymore
        next
    }
    print >> a[$3]
    close(a[$3])
}
END {                                # in the end 
    f++
    for(i in u)                      # print all uniques to last file
        print u[i] > f
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for this one. Could you make it Windows compatible? I ran it but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, it is awk as you had tagged and you need to install awk to run it.

Comment: I do have it installed on windows and have other scripts running properly. I am trying to use it in cmd and not working. Could you tell me what would be the command to run it properly from windows command line?

Comment: How is it _not working_? May you could copy and paste the actual code part (code between the single quotes) to a file (named `code.awk` later) and running it with `awk -f code.awk file`

Comment: I was actually copying the whole thing to a awk file and it was giving "." syntax error. Now it is working fine as it should.  I see the files are named by numbers. Having the number found in data as filename is much more useful. Nevertheless, this also works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I probably (apparently) missed the filenaming requirement, sorry about that. I also never read any manuals for any devices... I'll fix that in a bit (not the manual reading part).

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$NF]++
  next
}
arr[$NF]==1{
  print > ("unique.txt")
  next
}
arr[$NF]>1{
  outFile=$NF".txt"
  print >> (outFile)
  close(outFile)
}
'  Input_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                    ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when Input_file is being read first time.
  arr[$NF]++                ##Creating arr with index of last field and increasing it 1 each time it comes with same one.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
arr[$NF]==1{                ##Checking condition if any value(last field) occurs only 1 time in whole Input_file then do following.
  print > ("unique.txt")    ##Printing current line to unique.txt output file.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
arr[$NF]>1{                 ##Checking condition if last field comes more than 1 then do following.
  outFile=$NF".txt"         ##Creating outFile variable with last field .txt to it.
  print >> (outFile)        ##Printing current line to output file here.
  close(outFile)            ##Closing output file in backend to avoid "too many opened files" error.
}
'  Input_file Input_file    ##Mentioning Input_file(s) here.
```

Comment: thanks for the help, however, for some reason it is not working for me. It doesn't do anything after running the script.

Comment: I bet you didn't pass  the file name twice as Ravinder shows.